# Can you do shorter declarations in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, coding-style, declaration

I always write long declares, like:

```
private Dictionary<IPAddress, IWebSocketConnection> Dict = new Dictionary<IPAddress, IWebSocketConnection>();
```

Is there a way to write it like this:

```
private Dict = new Dictionary<IPAddress, IWebSocketConnection>();
```

Comment: It is not possible per say - you have to either do it by creating a var or, if you are going to be using a dictionary with the exact same type parameters repeatedly, you could create a custom class and extend the Dictionary with the type parameters.

Comment: Might be worth noting `var` isn't available if you're targetting earlier than .net 3.5

Comment: @retailcoder `var` is a feature of the compiler, not of the runtime. So it should work if your compiler supports C# 3.0 or newer, no matter what framework you are targeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For local variables, you could do:

```
var Dict = new Dictionary<IPAddress, IWebSocketConnection>();
```

Not for class fields, though.

Comment: Oops, [you’re right](http://ideone.com/J3gNJH). [This is why I use VB.NET, people!](http://ideone.com/NlBL39)

Comment: Will there any be any downside to using var? for example performance or intellisense?

Comment: No. `var` is evaluated at compile-time to take the type of the first value that is assigned to it. There is no performance impact, and Intellisense is able to resolve it as well.

Comment: Using `var` can affect readability in some cases though. Writing `var dog = new Dog()` is perfectly fine but writing something like `var temp = SomeMethod()` makes it difficult to determine what `temp` is supposed to be.

Comment: It can also keep you from making terrible mistakes. `List<long> list = getLongList(); foreach (int i in list) { ... }` will not even generate a warning, even though it potentially truncates your data. `for (var i in list) { ... }` will prevent that.

Comment: Your last sentence is both speculative and inaccurate. I remind you that Java does not have a unified type system, unsigned integer arithmetic, the decimal type, user-defined struct types, nullable value types, unsafe pointers, partial classes, anonymous types, first class properties, user-defined operators, indexers and conversions, object and collection initializers, explicit interface implementation, ref/out parameters, optional arguments, named arguments, yield return, extension methods, conditional methods, partial methods, correctly reified generic types...

Comment: ... constructor constraints on generic types, anonymous methods, lambdas, homoiconic expression trees, query comprehensions, dynamic language interop, type-inferred locals, checked arithmetic, verbatim strings, multidimensional arrays, conditional compilation, region directives, fixed size buffers and explicit stack allocation. If Java is "intensely copying" all the great features of C# they're doing an extraordinarily poor job of it. Do you care to revise your statement?

Comment: I was really not trying to get up anyones nose. It is just something I noticed over time. No offense intended.

Answer (score 1):

or you can also create a new class :)

create a subclass from `Dictionary<IPAddress, IWebSocketConnection>`

```
public class Dict : Dictionary<IPAddress, IWebSocketConnection> {
  //...
}
```

And use like that:

```
var dict = new Dict();
```

Comment: Not going to downvote but I don't think "shorter declarations" warrants inheritance...

Answer (score 1):

you can use alias:

```
using ShortName = Lib.SubFolder.ClassVeryLongName.SubClassEvenLongerName;
```

This has to go at the top of the file/namespace, just like regular **using**s.

then use it.

edit:

use it like this:

```
using Dict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Net.IPAddress, YourNamespcae.IWebSocketConnection>;
```

note: you need to specify the full class name as **System.Net.IPAddress**
I don't know what is IWebSocketConnection but you just add the namespce at the beginning.

then use it like:

**Dict dict1 = new Dict();**